# alignment in textfield does not work

Tags: ios, uitextfield, alignment

I want both my placeholder and typed text to be aligned in the center.

I tried both of these options for the two textfields I have, but still the placeholder and whatever I type are aligned left.

```
self.teamA_name.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.teamB_name.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

What am I missing?

Textfields are created through IB.

Comment: check your IBOutlet connection and in which method do you set this `self.teamA_name.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;`

Comment: @dopcn in my ViewDidLoad

Comment: @dopcn it was a customview in the end and placing that into layoutSubviews made it work. Please make it an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I didn't answer your question actually  so never mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,15, 20)];
_txtCityName.leftView = paddingView;
_txtCityName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Use this code to set inset..This works for me
Currently I'm setting padding view width as 15...change this as your requirement and make it in the center